# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UserStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a problem in SwiftUI. When I try to launch my simulator, an error occurred.
The simulator launch well but after a few seconds, an error message appears :

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UserStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for
UserStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0 2020-05-05
13:08:36.521073+0200 PLAN.YOUR.TRIP[55476:1340155] Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type
UserStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UserStore may be missing as an ancestor
of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0
(lldb)
```

This come from a file in which I use an other file named UserStore to connect my project to Firebase, this is where the error occurred :

```
 if user.showLogin { //     <--- RIGHT HERE

            ZStack {
                LoginView(showLogin: $showLogin)

                VStack {
                    HStack {

                        Spacer()

                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray6))
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.user.showLogin = false
                        }
                    }
               }
          }
```

The error says that there is a problem " No ObservableObject of type UserStore found " but I've created a file named " UserStore " in which I've put this :

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class UserStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLogged = false
    @Published var showLogin = false
    @Published var showReg = false
}
```

And to link this to my other file in which I use the @EnvironmentObject like this :

```
struct Home: View {
    @State var showProfile = false
    @EnvironmentObject var user: UserStore
    @State var showLogin = false
    @State var showReg = false
```

I can't understand the error because this exact same code was working yesterday but I've tried to uninstall an extension called " Hero " which was unused on my project and a suggestion said me to update my code into swift 5, this what I've done but after this a lot of other error appeared. I decided to recreate a project with the exact same construction and files, reinstall cocoa pods with the same code (without the " Hero pod ") and the bundle id is the same so this is not a problem between the Firebase and my project ...

I know this content is repetitive here but I've don't find anything working for me in all the other forum.

Sorry for my English which is not the best...

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: How are you creating `Home`? As the error message very clearly states, you need to call `.environmentObject` on it to inject `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In places, all, where you create `Home` instance, ie. do `Home()`, you *must* instead use

```
Home().environmentObject(UserStore())
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to call `.environmentObject` on it straight after init. You just need to make sure it is called before the first time you access or present `Home`.